# How do I pass a variable from js file to an html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, global

I have a webpage which utilizes javascript, and I have a .js file declared separately (I need it to be separately)
Here's what's in the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'input[name="rating"]', function() {
        var sf.gav = $(this).val();
        alert(sf.gav);
    });
});
```

However, no matter what I do or how I declare sf.gav, it is never saved so that I can use it later on the page (the code itself works and shows the number). It just says "undefined". Any advice?

Edit::
Thank you for your answers!
I'm going to clarify a bit: I am using a game engine called "tyranobuilder" and it has its own variables. Only its own variables can be passed to another code that I need, specifically, a button that "submits" the information (the whole page is just a giant swarm of radio buttons). Therefore, I was looking for a way to get a value from jquery that I can then pass on to the button (first declaring "f.value = sf.gav"), which will in turn set in motion another script. After that, the initial value passed by the jquery can be forgotten. 
This button, and the declaration "f.value = sf.gav", are, obviously, at the end of the radio buttons. So far, even with your generous attempts at helping, nothing works..

Comment: Where do you 'need to use it later in the page'? This sounds like a scope problem.

Comment: Well, it's actually for an html game, so everywhere. It must be stored forever.

Comment: You are probably accessing it too soon in other parts of the code (like before the document is ready)

Comment: If you need it stored 'forever' then I'd suggest putting it in localStorage or a cookie, as variables only exist as long as the page does. It would really help to see where in your code you need to use the value, and how you're accessing it, though.

Comment: you could use a cookie or localstorage. data in javascript only exists until you reload the page

Comment: Note `var sf.gav` is invalid syntax you do not declare object properties with `var` / `let`

Comment: It's scoped to be only available inside the click event handler - move the var *outside* document.ready but still assign it inside docready/click handler:  `var gav ; $(function() { gav = 123 ..` .  You might still have issues if you access it too soon.

Comment: Relevant post on How JavaScript Scope Works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is private to `$(document).on('click', 'input[name="rating"]', function() {});` event function. That's why you can't access it globally.

As I can understand you need to declare the variable globally like,

```
var sf = {gav: null}; // <--- like this.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'input[name="rating"]', function() {
        sf.gav = $(this).val();
        alert(sf.gav);
    });
});
```

So you can access it anywhere.

Comment: Note: global variables are mostly a bad idea, but this will solve the scoping issue.

Comment: @Liam yes of course!

Comment: Just highlighting a flaw in the general logic.